# VSTO: Email editor addin - getting current cursor position

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm writing an outlook email plugin which needs to insert HTML code where the pointer is currently located.

How can I read out the current cursor position in the email i'm currently editing? I'm writing an application level addin.

Maybe someone can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The Outlook object model provides three different ways for working with item bodies:

1. Body - a plain text.
2. HTMLBody - an HTML markup.
3. The Word Editor. Outlook uses Word as an email editor, so you can use it to format the email message. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class which represents the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in MSDN.

The simplest way to get the job done is to use the Word object model for modifying the message body. For example:

```
mail.GetInspector().WordEditor
```

Then you can use the Word object model for working with message body. The *Selection* property of the Word Application class will help you to identify the current cursor position.

Comment: Thank you. I need to use html email format. Is the word editor available for this email format?

Comment: Yes, Word is used as an email editor in Outlook and for rendering HTML as well.

Comment: I have get it rid with the WordEditor. Thank you.